# Cannot parse String date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am getting date as `string` in this format `2018-05-04T15:49:27+00:00` but cannot seem to be able to parse it with `SimpleDateFormat`. The `T` between year and time causing exception, I red about `SimpleDateFormat` class from Java docs but there is no mention of `T`. Now I am 
replacing the `T` with space and then parsing it but I wonder if this is the right solution. Just for the record `T` is not Tuesday it's always `T` no matter what date is.

Comment: No, replacing it is the wrong solution, you simply need to use the proper date time format for parsing, including a `'T'`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Its one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` method will even parse your string without any explicit formatter.

Comment: Your format is ISO 8601. It uses `T` to denote the beginning of the time part, to separate it from the date part.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Tip: Look for `OffsetDateTime` class. `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-05-04T15:49:27+00:00" )`  Never use the troublesome old legacy classes seen in both Answers on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below formater to parse the string `2018-05-04T15:49:27+00:00` to time.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need for `SimpleDateFormat` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

`T` is just plain text and therefore has no special meaning for `SimpleDateFormat`. You should put it into quotes then the plaintext is read "as it is"

If you use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ...` instead of just `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss ...` you should be fine.